# What bad things could an "attacker" do with my stolen ID's?

Tags: identity

So if someone steals my (ex.: I didn't teared up a piece of paper that had these and I throwed it away on the street) ID's like my:

- Full name
- Permanent address
- Birth date/place
- My mothers name
- Identification card number
- Telephone number

What bad could happen to my ID's?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the only piece of missing information needed to fill out the application for a Credit Card is your Social Security Number. Unfortunately [Social Security Numbers are very easy to guess](http://redtape.msnbc.msn.com/_news/2009/07/06/6345737-researchers-say-they-can-guess-your-ssn?lite), although the attacker would have to know when you where born and what state you were born in, but this can be obtained from public records.

Answer (score 4):

Well, besides this being a tremendous privacy concern you must worry about the effects it will have on your security. It could be something as insignificant as an attacker calling your phone attempting to social engineer you (with these ID's, it's possible that an attacker could impersonate an authority you trust because 'how else could he know these things?') to them being able to guess your security question(s), I believe 'mothers maiden name' is one of the most commonly chosen security questions.

I suppose if you really pissed someone off (who knew what they were doing), them simply having your address will give you a bad day (swatting anyone?).